# MediaWiki; MySQL database credentials stored, what file?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I have the task of now changing the credentials of the database out mediawiki is conneccted to. i have full access to all files etc.etc.

There are alot of files though, anyone know the "config" file name?

Answer (score 1):

LocalSettings.php in installation root.

Variable names are self-explanatory, but just in case - you want $wgDBuser and $wgDBpassword.